# How to use react-native-side-menu in react-native-router-flux?

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I made a react native app that has navigation bar and tabs at bottom of screen.
When I click a button in home screen, it appears left side menu.
There are one button in the side menu.
When I click the button, how should I do to go another screen?
I used  for navigation and tabs and  for left side menu.
I want a simple code snippet. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd highly recommend checking out the examples on this issue thread from `react-native-router-flux`:

https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/92

There are plenty of code snippets at that link above.

In our app we utilize `react-native-drawer` and it works well as described in the above thread. Here's a link to that repo: https://github.com/root-two/react-native-drawer